# Laravel with Laratrust - The Mix manifest does not exist?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laratrust

I did a fresh install of Laravel and Laratrust.

I enabled the Laratrust Panel and when I went to it I got the following...
[Screenshot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NATFO.png)

Other solutions I found said to do npm install and npm run dev or npm run production.
These did not help.
Any ideas?

Comment: You said npm run dev didn't help. Is there a mix-manifest.json in your public folder? Did it throw an error?

Comment: Correct, it did not fix my problem.  I have actually had several issues with Laratrust so I just uninstalled it completely and have been building a user / team / role / permission management system myself.

Answer (score 1):

I did solve this problem!

You need to write command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laratrust-assets --force
```

before or instead

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag="laratrust"
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can run it from the project folder on your server if you use Docker with Sail.


First:


`./vendor/bin/sail php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laratrust-assets --force`


Second:


`./vendor/bin/sail php artisan vendor:publish --tag="laratrust"`**

**You can run it from the project folder on your server.


First:
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laratrust-assets --force`


Second:
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag="laratrust"`**